# Idiomatic R to set "not found" data.table values to 0 or FALSE?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table that is the result of "counting" the number of matching rows in another table:

```
  set.seed(1)
  numRows = 100
  numTypes = 10
  dt = data.table(type=sample(numTypes, numRows, replace=T),
                  value=rbinom(numRows, 1, .5))
  counts = dt[, .N, by=.(type, value)]
```

I'd like to be able to do simple operations based on the returned value, but R returns integer(0) rather than 0 for non-matching rows:

```
c = counts[type==3 & value==1, N] 
print(c)
# [1] 7
c = counts[type==11 & value==1, N] 
print(c)
# integer(0)
```

This is well documented, but a problem when I try to use the result in a conditional:

```
if (c > 10) print("greater than 10")  # fails
# Error in if (c > 10) print("greater than 10") : 
#  argument is of length zero
```

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to convert the integer(0) that is returned for a non-existent count to a more tractable 0.  This is about the best I have:

```
c = counts[type==11, value==1]  # integer(0)
if (length(c) == 0) c = 0       # real 0
if (c > 10) print("greater than 10")  # no error
```

Obviously I could wrap it in a function, or do it on a single line, but it seems likely I'm missing builtin way to do it.  And while at it, it would be nice to handle NULL and NA (and any other non-numbers) as 0 too.   Is there a good general way to do this?

I'd like to avoid re-evaluating the lookup or retyping the expression.  Some languages use a short-circuit-or like this:

```
c = counts[type==1, value==1] || 0  # does not work in R
```

But I haven't found an R equivalent.  I could write my own function, but I'm not sure about performance or readability:

```
orZero = function(n) if (length(n) == 0 || is.na(n) || is.null(n)) 0 else n
```

Maybe there is a variant of `if` that treats integer(0) as FALSE?  Or perhaps there is an argument that can be passed to [.data.table() that will give me a 0 directly? I thought briefly that 'nomatch' might do it, but this seems to be different and used only for joins.

Comment: Perhaps `counts[, i1:=type==3 & value==1, N][, if(!any(i1)) 0 else N[i1]]`

Comment: Are you sure you actually *want* to do this? Is "no result" (`integer(0)`) the same as "result: 0" in your case?

Comment: What kind of operation are you doing after this ? This sounds like a XY problem.

Comment: Yes, I want to do this. I'm looking for a general solution to this problem, as it's one I come across frequently in R.   For context, though, this was the example that inspired me to write the question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171375/updating-the-head-or-tail-of-an-ordered-subset-of-rows-using-data-table-in-r